# Backup script: How to keep the last N entries?

Tags: bash, backup

For a backup script, I need to clean old backups. How can I keep the last N backups and delete the rest?

A backup is either a single folder or a single file and the script will either keep all backups in folders or files (no mixing).

If possible, I'd like to [avoid parsing of the output of `ls`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) Even though all the entries in the backup folder should have been created by the backup script and there should be no funny characters in the entry names, a hacker might be able to create new entries in there.

Comment: @kev http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 1):

This should do it (*untested!*):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -o errexit -o noclobber -o nounset -o pipefail
i=0
max=7 # Could be anything you want
while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9
do
    let ++i    
    if [ "$i" -gt "$max" ]
    then
        rm -- "$REPLY"
    fi
done 9< <(find /var/backup -type f -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]\.tar\.gz' -print0 | sort -rz)
```

Explained from the outside in:

1. Ensure that the script stops at any common errors.
2. Find all files in /var/backup (and *not* subdirectories) matching a `YYYY-MM-DD.tar.gz` format.
3. Reverse sort these, so the latest are listed first.
4. Send these to file descriptor 9. This avoids any problems with `cat`, `ssh` or other programs which read standard input by default.
5. Read files one by one from FD 9, separated by NUL.
6. Count files until you get past your given max.
7. Nuke the rest from orbit.

Comment: In my GNU find the default regextype is emacs, which does not support \d for [0-9]. Actually, none of the regextypes in GNU find support that, which are all BRE or ERE. With an ERE type, [0-9]{4} can be used.

Comment: @jordanm: Thanks, fixed by using the lowest common denominator. `[x]{n}` doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: in order for it to work you need something like `-regextype posix-extended` to use ERE.